# How to take a tuple as input, and return it as a new tuple, but only with odd numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a procedure called oddTuples, which takes a tuple as input, and returns a new tuple as output, where every other element of the input tuple is copied, starting with the first one. So if test is the tuple ('I', 'am', 'a', 'test', 'tuple'), then evaluating oddTuples on this input would return the tuple ('I', 'a', 'tuple'). I got 0.6/1 with this code:

```
def oddTuple(tup):
    b = 1
    if b % 2 != 0:
        d.append(tup[b])
        b += 1
    print (d)
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? In your example you're not returning anything, and you're never converting your list to a tuple. You can also use `enumerate` to get both the index and the value in a list, so that you don't have to maintain it manually.

Comment: Where are you defining `d`? Note that Python lists are 0-indexed (i.e. its first element has index 0).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with basic slicing.

```
tup = ('I', 'am', 'a', 'test', 'tuple')
tup[::2]
# ('I', 'a', 'tuple')
```

The syntax for slicing is `iterable[start:end:step]`. If you leave any of those `start`, `end`, or `step` blank, they default to the beginning, the end, and 1 respectively. So the above is going through the whole thing (beginning to end) but only selecting every other element.

If you need it in a method:

```
def odd_tuple(tup):
    return tup[::2]  # or print(tup) if you prefer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def oddTuple(tup):
    return tuple(tup[i] for i in range(0, len(tup), 2))
```